# Code Snippets for Aura components and LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am trying to create some vs code snippets for aura and LWC so I created one snippet file for javascript now it works in both the languages but is there a way I can restrict JS and html snippets to LWC only or also can someone please confirm how to create snippets for .cmp and .app files to be used on aura HTML, below is my js snippet which works in all sorts of js files and I and trying to restrict it to just lwc

```
    "Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": "gss",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question better asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but I'll include the essentials here.

First, you would need to create some new [languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview), something like `javascript-lwc` and `javascript-aura`. They will both be associated with `*.js` files.

Once you create your languages, which can just be extended from JavaScript, you then [associate](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) those languages using `files.associations` to restrict them by path: `**/lwc/**/*.js` and `**/aura/**/*.js`.

After this, you'll be able to associate snippets to each language. Some additional setup might also be necessary, but this should get you started.

Obviously, you can also do this for Aura and LWC markup as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help, created a new language associated it with files.associations now I am packaging this in an extension could you please help on how can I package files.associations in the extension. Currently, I have done from my vs code settings only.

Comment: @gs650x see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54356069/2132791) on [so]. Basically, you import 'workspace' from 'vscode', and then you can use the APIs to get/set workspace settings. You can do this on the initialization hook for your extension. Looking forward to seeing your extension 

Comment: Thank you and actually, I have already published my snippets extension on vs code market place https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GurjitSingh.SalesforceSnippets but right now it is only for LWC and Apex and once I will figure out  initialization hook of extension I will start posting for aura as well.

Comment: Please do let me know your valuable feedback and suggestions, thank you

Comment: Could you please help me with the file.associate I have posted the question on stack overflow as well but still no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191424/update-user-workspace-settings-from-vs-code-extension?noredirect=1#comment125841366_71191424

Comment: @gs650x My experience with building extensions is limited, but I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Always appreciate your help sir